# Left Hand Side , Right Hand Side Compiler Errors in Dart / Flutter List

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having a terrible time getting this program to run. I keep getting compiler troubles when I run the code. See specifics below.  Anybody understand what's going on here?

My code extract from file `TapScreenToo.dart`:

```
import 'profiles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cards.dart';

class PageTapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Profile> profileList;
  Key key;

  PageTapScreen({
    this.key,
    this.profileList,
  }) : super(key: key);    // constructor

  @override
  _PageTapScreenState createState() => new _PageTapScreenState();
}
```

The profile class in file `profiles.dart` (no import statement there):

```
class Profile {
  final String ttaKey;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String displayName;

  Profile({
    this.ttaKey,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.displayName,
  });
}
```

my profile list from file `demoProfiles.dart`:

```
import 'profiles.dart';

final List<Profile> demoProfiles = [
  new Profile(
    ttaKey: "0",
    imageUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/photo_0.jpg',
    displayName: 'abc',
    ),
  new Profile(
    ttaKey: "1",
    imageUrl: 'http:// ... etc
    ),
]
```

And all of this gets called in `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'tapScreenToo.dart';
import 'demoProfiles.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Key keyOne = PageStorageKey('pageOne');

...
@override
  void initState() {
    tapScreen = PageTapScreen(
      key: keyOne,
      profileList:  demoProfiles,        <--- error points here
    );
```

I'm getting a compiler message at the time of initiation:

```
compiler message: lib/main.dart:68:20: Error: A value of type 'dart.core::List<#lib1::Profile>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dart.core::List<#lib2::Profile>'.  
compiler message: Try changing the type of the left hand side, or casting the right hand side to 'dart.core::List<#lib2::Profile>'. 
compiler message:       profileList: demoProfiles,`
```

I've tried to cast `(List <Profile>)` but that seems to be a fail, or I'm just doing it wrong.

Note: when I remark out the error line, and debug step to the failure location, I can see that the values for both `keyOne` and `demoProfiles` are exactly as expected.  Note, these code snippets are located in  different files, linked via `import` commands.

As I look at the rest of the code, I can see where `import 'profiles.dart'` gets called multiple times.

I don't understand the error message.  I've also studied [this posting with a similar error,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568593/flutter-adding-an-image-to-canvas-error-on-compile) but I'm just not seeing what's going on with this code, nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the imports in the `main.dart`:

```
import 'tapScreenToo.dart';
import 'demoProfiles.dart';
```

Since the `main.dart` can only have `packages:` imports which are called absolute imports.

Therefore change the imports to:

```
import package:mypackage/path/tapScreenToo.dart
import package:mypackage/path/demoProfiles.dart
```

Check this:

[Error: A value of type 'List<#lib1::Data>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<#lib2::Data>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308407/error-a-value-of-type-listlib1data-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-ty)

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started#importing-libraries-from-packages

Comment: Wow. That totally nailed it.  Not intuitive, but it works.  Thx.

Comment: Np, according to what I saw is because both of these imports will have a different `runtimeType` thus you get that error, which means when you are debugging the app dart thinks that this variable is in a different file, that is why you add the absolute import

Comment: it worked. Thanks, didn`t get the point why it was the issue with import package name.

Comment: @NagendraBadiganti I think its just a bug, as here in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308407/error-a-value-of-type-listlib1data-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-ty it says that this is a known issue.